# Trim the blank line and then pick the nth array item

Tags: windows, powershell

So I have a Powershell code where I am trying to `Get-content` of a file, trimming the first blank line and then splitting the content in order to get the nth item in the array.
The issue is its giving me nth item of the second line of the file, while I need the nth item of the first line.
Here's my code.

```
$Ess_keys = "D:\Automation\Encryption\myKeys.txt"

Get-Content $Ess_keys | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } |ForEach-Object{
$splitUp = $_ -split "\s+"
$PKey = $splitUp[5]}
$Pkey
```

Here's what the file looks like:

>

> Public Key for Encryption: 27743,2195638463
>
> Private Key for Decryption: 2073750047,2195638463

When I run it, this is the output its giving

> PS C:\Users\wrtty> $pkey
>
> 2073750047,2195638463

As you can see, its picking the 5th array item in the second line. While I need it from the 1st line.
I also checked if its not trimming the 1st non-blank line. But when I run the below 2 set of codes, I can see its not trimming the first non-blank line.

```
PS C:\Users\wrtty> Get-Content $Ess_keys | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }
```

> Public Key for Encryption: 27743,2195638463
>
> Private Key for Decryption: 2073750047,2195638463

```
PS C:\Users\wrtty> Get-Content $Ess_keys | where {$_ -ne ""}
```

output

> Public Key for Encryption: 27743,2195638463
>
> Private Key for Decryption: 2073750047,2195638463

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are overwriting `$PKey` with each loop iteration. Then you are only outputting `$PKey` at the end. So you only get the last matched line.

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt, you are overwriting `$PKey` with each loop iteration. Then you are only outputting `$PKey` at the end. So you only get the last matched line.

Since it appears you already know the data format within the file, you can use a simple `Select-String` pattern match to get the data you want.

```
$pkeys = Select-String -Path "D:\Automation\Encryption\myKeys.txt" -Pattern "Public Key for Encryption: (\S+)" -AllMatches |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    }
$pkeys
```

The above code stores ***ALL*** public key matched data in `$pkeys`. If you only want to access the first match, then `$pkeys[0]` will suffice. The regex `(\S+)` matches consecutive non-white space characters.

Comment: If -all- matches are wanted, perhaps the `-Pattern` should be `"Public Key for ..cryption: (\S+)"`.

Comment: Decryption would be private key. So there would be slightly more deviation. I honestly don't know what the poster really wants. I "see" attempts to grab public key data only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment AdminOfThings 
Below solution worked for me.

```
Get-Content $Ess_keys | where {$_ -ne ""} |Select-Object -First 1| ForEach-Object{
$splitUp = $_ -split "\s+"
$PKey = $splitUp[5]}
```